# Django channels: No module named 'asgiref.sync'

Tags: python, django, django-channels

I am following this guide for channels tutorial (https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/channels/latest/channels.pdf) and after adding channels to top of `INSTALLED APPS`, adding `ASGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.routing.application'` to my setting file and creating following `routing.py`:

```
# .../routing.py
from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
      # (http->django views is added by default)
})
```

I am getting this error after running `python manage.py runserver`:

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.sync'`

I have following versions of libraries:

```
Django (1.11.5)
asgiref (1.1.2)
channels (2.0.2)
...
```

Can someone help me ? I am new to channels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the problem was with old version of `asgiref` I just had to update django and it updated also the asgiref package.

Answer (score 0):

Django supporting asynchronous module after version 3.0. So asgiref module will available after django versions>=3.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).