# getting this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.local'

Tags: python, django

> File "/home/user/myApp/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 4, in 
>       from asgiref.local import Local
>   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref.local'

code looks like this:

```
from asgiref.local import Local
self._connections = Local(thread_critical=True)
```

using python3.6 on ubuntu 16
please help

Comment: Can you tell me what editor you are using?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django channels: No module named 'asgiref.sync'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245396/django-channels-no-module-named-asgiref-sync)

Comment: `pip install asgiref==3.2.3` Try this