# Django ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'

Tags: python, django, batch-file

I have a Django service we are trying to schedule in conjunction with the main application that runs periodically to send automated emails via a batch script.

The Django application itself starts up fine, but when I try running the batch script, I get the following traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                                                        
File "C:\Program Files\compuweather\compuweather\webapp\management\commands\send_all_clients.py", 
line 2, in <module>     from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand                                                                   
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-3.2- 
py3.8.egg\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 13, in <module>                                                                                                                   
from django.apps import apps                                                                                          
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-3.2-py3.8.egg\django\apps\__init__.py", line 
1, in <module>       from .config import AppConfig                                                                                         
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-3.2-py3.8.egg\django\apps\config.py", line 7, 
in <module>         from django.utils.deprecation import RemovedInDjango41Warning                                                         
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django-3.2-py3.8.egg\django\utils\deprecation.py", 
line 5, in <module>                                                                                                                           
from asgiref.sync import sync_to_async                                                                              
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named asgiref
```

I find that odd considering I have the batch file set to run from an anaconda environment that has Asgiref installed. I can verify this with pip freeze. Here are the versions of the packages I'm using:

asgiref==3.3.1
Django==3.1.6

I saw a similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49245396/django-channels-no-module-named-asgiref-sync), that was due to the Django and asgiref packages being outdated. I've tried updating both asgiref and Django to the latest versions (those listed), but that also didn't help.

My best guess after looking through the traceback is either something is trying to use a deprecated package (hence the use of deprecation.py) or a path needs to be appended somewhere. If the former, is there an alternative I should be using?

For reference, here is the batch file I am trying to use:

```
call C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Scripts\activate.bat C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3 
call activate test
"C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\Python.exe" "C:\Program Files\compuweather\compuweather\webapp\management\commands\send_all_clients.py"
```

Comment: Try `py "C:\Program Files\compuweather\compuweather\webapp\management\commands\send_all_clients.py"`

Comment: I believe your venv is not activated correctly. And why don't you use the `manage.py` to run you custom management command in your batch ? Something like `python C:\Program Files\compuweather\compuweather\manage.py send_all_clients`

Comment: @Benbb96 no, it definitely activates correctly, but running it direct from the manage.py is a good suggestion. I will try that

Comment: `cmd /k` just opens a new empty `cmd.exe` instance, after completing the three commands above it, what are you expecting it to do? The environment you set up and activated was surely intended for the existing `cmd.exe` instance, not for the new one. Also your code does not indicate what your current directory is from the outset of your first `call`, command. As we've no idea what, or which variables were used or created with your avtivation commands, we have no way of knowing the current directory or the location of your modules, and cannot therefore tell you where it is supposed to find them.

Comment: @Compo well, that's not quite accurate. cmd /k returns to the existing terminal instance. It keeps all the same configs, and thus is useful for debugging in the event of an error. It'll load the environment and show all error messages rather than closing the terminal. As far as the paths, that to me would imply you want to know the path to the conda environment and packages available. I can add that, but really shouldn't be necessary. If sys.path.append is needed somewhere, I just need to know where to add that. I know what path would go in there

Comment: Please open a Command Prompt window, type `cmd /?`, press the `[ENTER]` key and read its usage information. In the case above, you're effectively using it as a pause command, within which, you could if you wish, examine stuff. The point I'm making is that I have no idea how `cmd /k` is relevant to your question, i.e. it is not a [mcve]. We cannot tell you where to add things if we do not know what your code is, current directory, or module location environment/path is. Your message is telling you that something cannot be found, how do we know its location based upon your provided information?

Comment: @Benbb96 that worked. Do you want credit for the answer? If so, post if and I will accept and upvote. Didn't know it needed to go through the manage.py

Comment: Happy to read that ! I've posted my answer, thanks @ZachRieck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `manage.py` to run your custom management command from your batch and have access to your project environment :

```
python C:\Program Files\compuweather\compuweather\manage.py send_all_clients
```